# PHP - /tmp permission error

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, tmp

Basically, I have an `.htaccess` file, with `php_value session.auto_start` set to `1`.
So my session will start in any file.

However, now I have a script in my `/functions` folder, but it gives an error about the permissions of the `/tmp`, resulting in `"Failed to write session data"`, **though it doesn't  use**, start or do anything with the session.

Yet this produces an error, and to me, it looks like it cannot find the `/tmp` folder, which I do have. Files directly in my root folder (`/`) don't have this a problem.
I also tried setting the permissions of `/tmp` to `777`, to no avail.

Thanks in advance

---

The error I'm getting

```
Warning: Unknown: open(/tmp/sess_cfed7db100fd58b62eaca2a519ebaf7a, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
```

---

The script itself:

```
<?php
define ('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
require('connect.php'); //This file doesn't use any sessions as well

if(isset($_POST['signupemail'])){
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['signupemail']);
    $thearray = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE email=\"".$email."\""));

    if($thearray[0] > 0){
        echo '"This emailaddress is already in use"';
        exit;
    }
    echo "true";


} else if(isset($_POST['uname'])){

    if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,16}$/ ',$_POST['uname'])){
        echo '"<small>Please only use alphanumeric characters, underscores and hyphens</small>"';
        exit;
    }

    $uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['uname']);
    $thearray = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE uname=\"".$uname."\"")); 
    $forbiddennames = array(1 => 'super-user','superuser', 'root', 'admin', 'administrator', 'system', 'website', 'site', 'owner', 'manager', 'founder','moderator');    

    if(in_array(strtolower($_POST['uname']), $forbiddennames)) {
        echo '"'.$_POST['uname'].' is a forbidden username"';
        exit;
    } 
    if($thearray[0] > 0){
        echo '"This username is already in use, please choose another"';
        exit;
    } 


    echo "true";

}
?>
```

I get the error when I just browse manually to my script, so without any `$_POST` parameters set. I use this script to verify one's email and/or password, and when checking, it stops, not knowing what to do with the result (gotten by `AJAX`).

Answer (score 0):

I think i remember some php.ini setting that prevents access to files that are not in the webserver's directory tree. I don't know if that applies to files that are generated internally by php, though.

If you're running on Red Hat Enterprise linux, or some derivative like CentOs or Scientific Linux, it might also be a problem with selinux. Check if the problem goes away if you set selinux to permissive (sudo setenforce Permissive). If that "fixes" the problem, think twice about leaving selinux in Permissive mode, especially if your server is reachable from the internet, better learn about selinux and relabeling.

Comment: open_basedir is the directive. Still, the descriptions says "scripts may not open files outside", which makes me think it will *probably* not apply to session files which are generated "inside" php.

Comment: `open_basedir` is usually accompanied with a `open_basedir restriction in effect` message.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm on a relatively restricted host. I can't access php.ini (but I can use `php_value`s though), or open the SSH. And the script is in `/functions`, and that's in my directory tree, right? It's just not in my root folder `/`. And as @user555 said, I'm not sure whether this is the problem, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Your script in /functions may be in your directory tree, but /tmp is not .. if it's really /functions, and not /home/yourname/functions, then your php files seem to run in a chrooted environment where /tmp just isn't accessible.

Comment: @Isaiah You can find out what `open_basedir` is set to using `phpinfo()`

Comment: Thank you. It says my `open_basedir` is set to `/home/matthdc58/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/`.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, it turned out to be browser-related.
When I tested it in FireFox, no problem.
In Google Chrome, big problem.

I don't know what it was, but after deleting the cache, cookies, everything from my site, it worked perfectly. Seemed like it was searching for an old session.

Comment: It might have been an issue with pre-existing sessions, which PHP was trying to "get back". If you tested with Chrome before and had a session, Firefox will give you a new one. A Chrome "incognito" window would have worked as well, probably. Perhaps you changed something like the PHP file handler, and PHP can't access what it created before.

Comment: @PeerBr, yes it probably was.